# C++11 take ownership of unique_ptr by the raw pointer or reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

**Edit**
I suppose the code below would assume I have an overloaded version of addChild() that accepts a Sprite already wrapped in a unique_ptr, where taking ownership would be fine. Just thought I'd mention that before someone else did. :) . I made up all the code here after a very long day, so please take it as pseudo code quality meant only to demonstrate the issue at hand.

**Original Question**

I'm writing a framework where there is a display list, parents/children etc. I'm thinking that using `unique_ptr<Sprite>` for example is the way to go here, since when you add a child to a parent display object, it's only logical that the parent now becomes the sole owner of that child.

However, there will be methods available such as `getChildAt(index)` and `getChildByName`, etc, which I believe should return a reference or pointer value, since these methods are simply meant to expose a child to operations, not transfer ownership.

Finally, the issue and the reason for this question, is in the following situation. Lets assume we have two `Sprite` objects which are children of the root of display list, `Stage`. Let's say we have a third child Sprite.

```
Stage newStage;
std::unique_ptr<Sprite> parentOne(new Sprite);
std::unique_ptr<Sprite> parentTwo(new Sprite);
newStage.addChild(parentOne); //Stage takes ownership of parentOne
newStage.addChild(parentTwo); //Stage takes ownership of parentTwo

std::unique_ptr<Sprite> someChild(new Sprite);
parentOne->addChild(someChild) //parentOne takes ownership of someChild.
```

Now, somewhere else lets say in the code base of the game or whatever using this framework, `someChild` is accessed via `getChildAt(int index);`.

```
Sprite& child = parentOne->getChildAt(0);
```

It would be perfectly legal for the following to then happen.

```
parentTwo->addChild(child);
```

The `addChild` method handles removing the child from it's previous parent, if a parent exists, so that the new parent can now make this child part of its section of the display list.

I'm returning the child(ren) from each sprite as a reference or pointer, because we don't want to hand off ownership (in methods such as `getChildAt()`), just provide access to the child. We don't want to hand it off as a `unique_ptr` and have it fall out of scope and die.

However, as I say, it would be perfectly legal and normal for this child (now accessed by a reference or pointer) to be passed off to another container (lets say in a drag and drop operation, dragging an item from one list to another). The problem we have now is that the unique ownership needs to be transferred from one parent to another, but we only have a reference or raw pointer.

I'm wondering what a sane solution to this problem would be. If I return a pointer, is it possible to transfer the ownership correctly at this stage?

```
void Sprite::addChild(Sprite* newChildToOwn)
{
    /* by checking newChildToOwn->parent we can see that the child is already owned
    by someone else. We need to not only remove the child from that parents' part of the
    display list and add it here, but transfer exclusive object ownership of newChildToOwn
    to this->.
    */
}
```

Comment: Am I missing something or why don't you take advantage of move semantics?

Comment: Within the scope of Sprite::addChild(Sprite* someOtherSprite), there is no reference to the unique_ptr that is already managing someOtherSprite...

Comment: See the answers below + the discussion on DrYaps answer for more.

Comment: I would call it `moveChild` or `takeChild`, and make sure it takes ots argumemt in a `move` only way (either rvalue reference, or `unique_ptr`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To transfer ownership you need to have access to the `unique_ptr` as the raw pointer knows nothing of how it is being used.

Would it work to have the remove child method return the `unique_ptr` so that the object is kept alive during the transfer and the `Sprite` will be able to take the ownership? This will allow references to be used in other places as you have already.

Comment: That's very interesting. Actually removeChild() should return a unique_ptr to the child, since once removed if the object is not captured for use elsewhere, it should die. I suppose then I could, within addChild(), simply do child->parent->removeChild(child) to obtain the unique_ptr.

Comment: That's right. As a side note be careful with the raw references as they could become invalid if the object is completely removed from the tree as those references will become invalid. `shared_ptr` would be more appropriate in that case.

Answer (score 6):

The release method gets you the pointer to the object and releases it from the unique_ptr

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release

For your structure, you should probably have method called releaseChild(index) that handles you the ownership by returning pointer.

Comment: +1. You and DrYap have pointed to the exact same solution. Great, now I'm left with how to mark as correct, since you are both correct as far as where you were pointing to for the solution.